# Telegram bots: How much API keys can I generate?

Tags: bots, telegram

is there a limit to generate API keys via botfather?

Documentation doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit is set to **20 bots**, [this is what you see if you try to create the 21th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnAaj.jpg)